# Nucleophile substitution in nonclassical carbocation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

In nucleophilic substitution of exo-2-norbornyl brosylate, carbocation formation is the rate determining step and the carbocation formed is: (in equilibrium)

[image]

After forming carbocation, the nucleophile will fill its electron on newly formed the vacant orbitals:

[image]

But this is not the product given in the book by FA Carey. 
The given product is:

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the equilibrating structure shown in the first line was finally proved to be incorrect recently, after many years of debate, by successfully obtaining an x-ray crystal structure of the 2-norbonyl cation. See [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/341/6141/62.full) for the paper.

Comment: What about the final product?